# Finding the Indexes of a minimum sum subarray recursively

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to find the substring of the lowest sum in a given array, i.e {2, **-3**, **-5**, 6, 7,} giving -8 adding the bolded numbers. I found a way to retrieve the sum recursively but all the program does is retrieve the sum but not the indexes

```
using namespace std;

int min(int a, int b) {
return (a < b)? a : b;
}

int min(int a, int b, int c) {
   return min(min(a,b), c);
} 

int minCrossingSum(int a[], int l, int m, int h){

   int sum = 0;
   int leftSum = INT_MAX;
   for(int i = m; i >= l; i--){
      sum += a[i];
      if (sum < leftSum) leftSum = sum;
   }

   sum = 0;
   int rightSum = INT_MAX;
   for(int i = m+1; i <= h; i++){
      sum += a[i];
      if (sum < rightSum) rightSum = sum;
   }

   return leftSum + rightSum;
} 


int minSubArrayDaC(int a[], int start,  int arraySize) {

   if (start == arraySize) 
      return a[start];

   int m = ((start + arraySize)/ 2);

   return min(minSubArrayDaC(a, start, m),
     minSubArrayDaC(a, m+1, arraySize),
     minCrossingSum(a, start, m, arraySize));

}

int main()
{
   int arr[] = {2, 3, -4, -5, 7};
   int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
   int min_sum = minSubArrayDaC(arr, 0, n-1);

   printf("Minimum contiguous sum is %d\n", min_sum);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you are getting and an output of what you expect to get, should help others figure out what's going on.

Comment: i get the correct output with the given array at the bottom. I need the first and last index of the subarray that adds to the output that it gives me. So the code given outputs -9 and the subarray is obviously {-4,-5} but I need the program to keep track of the first and last element of the correct solution.